# Funcion de PHP para comprar datos contra una tabla creada con un FOR

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap, funciones, modal

Tengo una tabla en html de turnos que es creada dinamicamente con un FOR teniendo como limitadores los horarios que trabajan los doctores y necesito crear un SELECT en un modal con los horarios disponibles pero no encuentro la forma de comparar los horarios que ya poseen turnos (que obtengo de una consulta) con los que son generados por el FOR.
pensaba obtenerlo con un if y luego pasarlo por una funcion a jquery y rellenar el SELECT con un .html()

```
  $option = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(turnos.dia,'%H:%i') as dia FROM turnos WHERE dia LIKE '".$strFecha."%' AND medico='".$medID."' ORDER BY dia ");

for ($a=$horaDesde;$a<=$horaHasta;$a++) { /*en que horarios trabajan traidos de una tabla sql*/

  foreach ($option as $key => $value) {

    if ($value['dia']!==$a.":00") {"<option>".$a.":00</option>";}
    if ($value['dia']!==$a.":15") {"<option>".$a.":15</option>";}
    if ($value['dia']!==$a.":30") {"<option>".$a.":30</option>";}
    if ($value['dia']!==$a.":00") {"<option>".$a.":45</option>";}
  }
```

si realizo esto compara cada horario que posee turno con toda la tabla uno por uno

Comment: Considerando que para cualquier valor de la query se cumple que es igual a uno de los horarios disponibles, **y distinto a todos los demás**. lo que estás haciendo  es imprimir todos los horarios posibles. Tu lógica debiera empezar obteniendo todos los turnos ya cubiertos por algún médico. Luego ejecutar tu consulta dejando afuera todos los que están cubiertos.

Comment: claro lo que intento es eso , hasta intente pasar los valores a array y luego compararlos con array_diff pero tienen que tener el mismo identificador para que me devuelva el valor diferente

Comment: ok volvamos atrás. Quieres asignar un doctor a un horario para que, por ejemplo, un pabellón nunca quede sin un residente? O quieres un sistema de horas donde se puedan agendar consultas acorde a los horarios libres? Si es lo segundo, podrías pegar la consulta para obtener los horarios que ya tienen turnos? ¿Qué tipo de dato tiene el campo día? ¿Es time, datetime, timestamp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion provando con el array_diff()

```
 $option = mysql_query("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(turnos.dia,'%H:%i') as dia FROM 
 turnos WHERE dia LIKE '".$strFecha."%' AND medico='".$medID."' ORDER BY dia 
 ");
 for ($a=$horaDesde;$a<=$horaHasta;$a++) {
 $select[]= $a.':00';
$select[]=$a.':15';
$select[]=$a.':30';
$select[]=$a.':45';  
} 
foreach($option as $value){
$turnos[]=$value['dia'];
}

$resultado = array_diff($select, $turnos);
$horariosDisponibles = NULL;
foreach ($resultado as $key => $value) {
$horariosDisponibles .= '<option>'.$value.'</option>';
}
return $horariosDisponibles;
}
```